# ERROR: Can't find Ruby library file or shared library cocoapods

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

[image]

getting this error.

I am not able to run pod install command while I have a proper cocoa pod install in my system , but when I am run gem which cocapods then its not showing me version of cocoa pods version .
may I know what we have to do.

```
admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Air SockerApp_Client  % sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

what I have done. remove HomeBrew, cocapods , rvm , ruby . each and everything I have deleted and then reinstall multiple time, but not able to solve then issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the similar issue. Any solution for it please.